# C# conversion failed when converting nvarchar to int

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert values to my database but I keep getting the error

> "conversion failed when converting the nvarchar 'Year' value to
>   datatype int"

in c#. I don't know how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save this book?", "Saving Record", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //open connection to the database
            cn.Open();
            //command to be executed on the database
            cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Books(BookTitle, Edition, Genre, Author, Publisher, Year, ISBN) VALUES (@BookTitle, @Edition, @Genre, @Author, @Publisher, @Year, @ISBN )", cn);
            //set paramaters value
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@booktitle", txtBook.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edition", txtEdition.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genre", txtGenre.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", txtAuthor.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher", txtPublisher.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", txtYear.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", txtISBN.Text);
            //ask db to execute query
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //close connection
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Record has been sucessfully saved!");
            Clear();
            frmlist.LoadRecords();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: My assumption is you aren't storing `year` as a text field in your database, for which `txtYear.Text` will need to be converted to an `int`

Comment: I do have a textbox where i'll be inputting the year to be stored in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Year` is a string type and needs to be converted to a number (int). You can use something like

`cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", int.Parse(txtYear.Text));`

Make sure that the year text is not empty and convertible to int.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the year field in your table be an integer, you should be binding an integer variable to it:

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", Int64.Parse(txtYear.Text));
```

Comment: @stuartd Because the OP did not include its schema.  If the target `year` column be a 16 bit integer, then most likely the driver can still sort things out.  You're right...it is unlikely that a year would require extra space, but if I had to choose not knowing anything about the data I would use `Int64.Parse`

Comment: Yeah, this is just converted to sql anyway, the integral size wont matter. Though on saying that the chances of the year being over `2147483647` would be small :) but know knows

Comment: I get that it doesn't matter, unless we all live to the year 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 - was just wondering why not just plain `int.Parse`. Sometimes you find interesting and/or useful things out by asking dumb questions..

Comment: Well people are saying that 60 is the new 40 `:-)`

Comment: The proper answer here isn't to parse the field. Its to change the field to a number input so it doesn't need to be parsed, thus preventing invalid input exceptions.

Comment: @boylec1986 I can't see the actual code which is doing that though.

Comment: In that case it would be a more resilient design to assume the text could be anything and check for parse-ability using int.TryParse rather just int.Parse - otherwise this is inviting a very nasty user-facing exception.

Comment: This answer will work, but it bears mentioning that [`AddWithValue` is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Add your parameters properly and this sort of problem will happen less often.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the value first

```
String yr = txtYear.Text;
int yr = Convert.ToInt32(yr);

cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year",""+yr );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you simply add int.Parse(txtYear.Text) as some of the other comments suggest, and the user enters any non-digit characters in the txtYear field you are going to get an exception.

You ought to change your text box to a number input so the value is an integer and you won't have to bother parsing it and hoping users input numbers only because that will be enforced by the number input itself.

Checkout this article on numeric inputs in Windows Forms:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-a-textbox-accepting-only-numbers-in-windows-forms1

That being said, if you are being forced to use a text input for some reason:

I would try and parse `txtYear.Text` as an integer using `int.TryParse(txtYear.Text, out int year)` before passing it into the SQL command. You can do something like the following at the top of the function to check the field and throw a more meaningful exception if the user has entered text into the field instead of all numbers:

```
if(!int.TryParse(txtYear.Text, out int year))
{
  throw new Exception("Only digits are allowed in the year field");
}

//the rest of your code goes here
//and use the year variable for the @year parameter
```

Comment: `int.TryParse(txtYear.Text, out int year)`